# Chrome Kiosk Mode close Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

Is it possible to close Chrome in Kiosk Mode via Javascript call?

`window.close();` isn't working due to security reasons. Is there another way when i change configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
javascript:window.close();
```